# Android HttpClient to just send data to server using get request

Tags: android, get, httpclient

I want to access a parameterized url with Android. All it has to do is "load" the page so that it does what its supposed to do (update database with parameters given).

I was having trouble just loading the url so I watched a video on regular HttpClient activity -- just waiting for the response and gathering that information. I figured that it would still be loading the page and therefore also letting that page execute. I can't even get that to run the page correctly or gather a response.

Here's the code I used:

```
String url = "http://www.removed.com?param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2;

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8 );
                test.setText(reader.readLine());
                webs.close();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error in conversion: ", e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error in connection: ", e.toString());
        }
```

Please let me know what I can do to get this to execute the page and update the database. If I put in the parameters manually into a browser, it works.

Comment: what happens when you run the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted where you're running this or what the error is, but the first two things that come to mind are:

- Do you have INTERNET permissions set in the manifest?
- If this is Honeycomb, is this running in a separate thread? - As of 3.0 you can't run HTTP requests in the main display thread.

Comment: I just added the permission. Before, I was getting a red UnknownHostException and then my URL. I'm still getting the error after, but it is black now. And as far as I  know, it is not in a separate thread. The only thing 'new' I have made was new Intents.

Comment: it needs to be in a separate thread if you're compiling for 3.0 or later. And an UknownHostException means it can't find the host :)

Comment: I think I was compiling for earlier than 3.0, but I tried to switch to 4.0.3 halfway through. Not sure if I was successful or not. Any way to check for sure? And I can't imagine why it says it can't find the host. The url I'm giving it is exactly what it is.

Comment: Actually, I know what I did with the url. Works exactly as intended now. Is there any way to *just* load the url and now read a response? I tried just stopping after declaring the HttpGet and doing `httpclient.execute(httpget)` but that doesn't work.

Comment: I got everything eventually. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments in answers I think U are searching for response code. I am posting you code here which is working well in my code

```
String urlGET = "http://www.removed.com?param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2;

HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(urlGET);
    // if you are having some headers in your URL uncomment below line 
    //getMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/form-data");
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);

        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseBody = null;

        if (entity != null) {
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
          //here you get response returned from your server
            Log.e("response = ", responseBody);

            // response.getEntity().consumeContent();

        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
         // do whatever you want to do with your json reponse data

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```